# I lost files and folders on Ubuntu on my other locations disk

Tags: 23.04

Files and folders created on Ubuntu on the other locations disk disappeared. I saved my program files and videos a couple of days ago and I just tried to open it today but neither the created folders and files can be found on the disk form the "other locations". This happened on Ubuntu lunar lobster. How do I get back all my lost files and folders?

Comment: You've provided few details; we don't know what 23.04 system, be it desktop or server. You've also not said if it's an installed system, nor details as to file-system(s) involved, but if it was a *live* system then the *fs* is in RAM and is lost by design on shutdown/reboot with a new system starting on next boot.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** You mention the "other locations disk." What was the name of this disk? The Other Locations tab in Nautilus will show you shares of your own computer, and also connected shares like another computer on your network. Did you save your files to one of these external shares perhaps? If so, you may not have actually lost your files, as they may still be on whatever share you saved to initially.